Flutter pub upgrade fails for dependency constraints but there are none
I have a flutter project I created last year, and now I want to update it to the latest versions. But I can't:
forest@forestg$ flutter pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies... (1.1s)
Downloading packages... 
  csslib 0.17.3 (1.0.0 available)
  leak_tracker 10.0.4 (10.0.5 available)
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing 3.0.3 (3.0.5 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.8.0 (0.11.1 available)
  meta 1.12.0 (1.15.0 available)
  test_api 0.7.0 (0.7.1 available)
  vm_service 14.2.1 (14.2.2 available)
No dependencies changed.
7 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

Ok, I run the said command:
forest@forestg$ flutter pub outdated
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name  Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest  

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

dev_dependencies: all up-to-date.
all dependencies are up-to-date.
forest@forestg:$ 

nothing..? o.O
my pubspec.yaml:
name: workout_generator_x
description: A randomized workout generator
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'
  flutter: ">=2.2.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  provider: ^6.0.5
  flutter_html: 3.0.0-beta.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.15
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  intl: ^0.19.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.12
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.0
  rename_app: ^1.3.1
  file_picker: ^8.0.3
  just_audio: ^0.9.15
  google_mobile_ads: ^5.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"


  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/lang/
    - assets/flags/
    - assets/app_database/
    - assets/icons/svg/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/beeps/

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icons/app_icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/icons/app_icon.png"
    background_color: "#hexcode"
    theme_color: "#hexcode"
  windows:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/icons/app_icon.png"
    icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
  macos:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/icons/app_icon.png"


I tried flutter clean, or upgrade with --major-version all the same.
forest@forestg$ flutter --version
Flutter 3.22.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision a14f74ff3a (5 days ago) • 2024-05-22 11:08:21 -0500
Engine • revision 55eae6864b
Tools • Dart 3.4.1 • DevTools 2.34.3
forest@forestg$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.1, on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 6.5.0-35-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!


Try to manually update environment SDK versions to actual

# Actual SDK's
environment:
  # Dart SDK supported versions
  sdk: '>=3.4.1 <4.0.0'

  # Flutter SDK supported versions
  flutter: '3.22.1'

and run upgrader again.
On same result try to upgrade all using in pubspec packages manually to actual versions.
About all other packages with never version on flutter pub upgrade you can just nevermind - it can be because of some inner dependencies in other usage packages, it's ok.
